# How to get money from users mobile phone using Java application?

Tags: java, android, mobile-phones, nokia, currency

How to get money from users phone using Java application?
So I want to create simple casual game, I want to charge users if they want to pass some extra layers. I want to create an app first of all for android, it'll be opensource. Than to port in on nokia and other Java enabeld devices. Are there any tutorials\matereals on how to do such thing? May be not on android on something else like Nokia? (BTW I want to transfer money to some banc account on PayPal visa or anething or to my own sim card at least...)

Comment: Could you please reformulate your title so it doesn't look like you're trying to do something not so unethical...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the [PayPal SOAP API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference) if what you want is for users to buy something in-game.

As long as you can make web requests from your device it is easily portable.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with [The Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) for Android to get yourself acquainted with the platform and go from there.  Making money from the product is a matter of pricing it on the Android Market.

Answer (score 1):

Requiring a game to have an internet connection just for paypal could be a little annoying. Maybe consider a binary pricing model where you have a free version without some features and a premium version with all the bells and whistles. This would also make it so that users don't need to use alternative payment methods to what they are used to on the store.

Answer (score 0):

For real Java<sup>TM</sup> applications, The [Java Store](http://store.java.com/) should be coming soon.

(I guess I should include disclosure/disclaimer here. I am an Oracle employee. The statements and opinions expressed here are my own and do not necessarily represent those of Oracle Corporation.)